# Call to get EMR results always returns empty state collection even when EMR job done

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

For IP reasons, I'm not able to post full source code.  However, I made a call to submit an Amazon Elastic Map Reduce Job (EMR) which now runs to completion.  Previously it failed with essentially a file not found error.

```
RunJobFlowResult result=emr.runJobFlow(request);
```

succeeds and I can get the job flow ID from it.

Later, I have a loop polls for the status by first
    DescribeJobFlowsRequest request=new DescribeJobFlowsRequest(jobFlowIdArray);
I check each state in a loop by calling
    request.getJobFlowStates()

Unfortunately, that call always returns an empty collection, regardless of whether the job is running, failed or succeeded.  How can I get at least some indication of what's going on?

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonElasticMapReduceClient client = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);
client.setEndPoint("elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");

StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();
StepConfig enableDebugging = new StepConfig()
.withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
.withHadoopjJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());


String[] arguments={...} // Custom jar arguments

HadoopJarStepConfig jarConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig();
jarConfig.setJar(JAR_NAME);
jarConfig.setArgs(Arrays.asList(arguments));

StepConfig runJar = new     StepConfig(JAR_NAME.substring(JAR_NAME.indexOf('/')+1),jarConfig);

RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
.withName("...")
.withSteps(runJar)
.withLogUri("...")
.withInstances(
     new JobFlowInstancesCOnfig()
       .withHadoopVersion("1.0.3")
        .withInstanceCount(5)
         .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
         .withMasterInstanceType("m1.small")
          .withSlaveInstanceType("m1.small");

RunJobFlowResult result = client.runJobFlow(request);
String jobFlowID=result.getJobFlowID();
List<String> describeJobFlowIdList=new ArrayList<String>(1);
describeJobFlowIdList.add(jobFlowID);

String lastState="";
boolean jobMonitoringNotDone=true;
while(jobMonitoringNotDone){
    SescribeJobFlowsRequest describeJobFlowsRequest=
        new DescribeJobFlowsRequest(describeJobFlowIdList);
    // Call to describeJobFlowsRequest.getJobFlowStates() always returns
    // empty list even when job succeeds or fails.
    for(String state : describeJobFlowsRequest.getJobFlowStates()){
        if(DONE_STATES.contains(state)){
            jobMonitoringNotDone=false;
        } else if(!lastState.equals(state)){
            lastState = state;
            System.out.println("Job "+state + " at "+ new Date().toString());
        }
    }
    try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not even create a minimally functional example the reproduces your problem?

Comment: I updated it to give a minimalist view of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The code above was missing a call similar to

```
DescribeJobFlowsResult describeJobFlowsResult =      client.describeJobFlows(describeJobFlowsRequest);
```

This got me a solution that works, but unfortunately Amazon deprecated the method but didn't provide an alternative.  I wish I had a non deprecated solution so this is only a partial answer.